# Should i update the BIOS

Tags: rootkits, bios

I was reading about BIOS vulnerabilities and rootkits that have flashed malicious code to the BIOS in order to maintain access after a factory reset/operating system install or a hard drive replacement i was wondering if i should update the BIOS if a update is available i read online that it is generally not a good idea to update the BIOS so from a security standpoint should i? Or is there a better method to prevent malware from gaining access to the BIOS and can said malware flash the code remotely or physical access required?

Answer (score 3):

If there is an update available for your BIOS, then you should absolutely update it. Many vulnerabilities in firmware are found and only fixed through an update of the BIOS itself. Forgoing an update could leave you exposed to known vulnerabilities, including those that could allow malware to persist in the BIOS.